# Error in running Azure Data Factory Pipeline. Linked Service Reference not found

Tags: azure-machine-learning-service, azure-data-factory

I am facing the below issue in creating an Azure Machine Learning Batch Execution activity to execute a scoring ML experiment. Please help:

**Please let me know if any other relevant information is needed. I am new to this so, please help**

1. Created an AzureML Linked Service as below:

   ```
   {
   "name": "PredictionAzureML",
   "properties": {
   "typeProperties": {
   "mlEndpoint": "https://ussouthcentral.services.azureml.net/workspaces/xxxxx/jobs",
   "apiKey": "xxxxxxxx=="
   },
   "type": "AzureML"
   }
   }
   ```
2. Created Pipeline as below:

   ```
   {
   "name": "pipeline1",
   "properties": {
   "description": "use AzureML model",
   "activities": [
   {
   "name": "MLActivity",
   "description": "description",
   "type": "AzureMLBatchExecution",
   "policy": {
   "timeout": "02:00:00",
   "retry": 1,
   "retryIntervalInSeconds": 30
   },
   "typeProperties": {
   "webServiceInput": "PredictionInputDataset",
   "webServiceOutputs": {
   "output1": "PredictionOutputDataset"
   }
   },
   "inputs": [
   {
   "name": "PredictionInputDataset"
   }
   ],
   "outputs": [
   {
   "name": "PredictionOutputDataset"
   }
   ],
   "linkedServiceName": "PredictionAzureML"
   }
   ]
   }
   }
   ```
3. Getting the below error:

   ```
    {
   "errorCode": "2109",
   "message": "'linkedservicereference' with reference name 'PredictionAzureML' can't be found.",
   "failureType": "UserError",
   "target": "MLActivity"
   }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Please use "Trigger" instead of "Debug" in the UX. You need publish your pipeline first before click "Trigger" Button. 
Please follow [this doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/transform-data-using-machine-learning) to update your payload. It should look like the following.

`{
    "name": "AzureMLExecutionActivityTemplate",
    "description": "description",
    "type": "AzureMLBatchExecution",
    "linkedServiceName": {
        "referenceName": "AzureMLLinkedService",
        "type": "LinkedServiceReference"
    },
    "typeProperties": {
        "webServiceInputs": {
            "<web service input name 1>": {
                "LinkedServiceName":{
                    "referenceName": "AzureStorageLinkedService1",
                    "type": "LinkedServiceReference"
                }, 
                "FilePath":"path1"
            }, 
            "<web service input name 2>": {
                "LinkedServiceName":{
                    "referenceName": "AzureStorageLinkedService1",
                    "type": "LinkedServiceReference" 
                }, 
                "FilePath":"path2"
            }

        },
        "webServiceOutputs": {
            "<web service output name 1>": {
                "LinkedServiceName":{
                    "referenceName": "AzureStorageLinkedService2",
                    "type": "LinkedServiceReference"

                }, 
                "FilePath":"path3"
            }, 
            "<web service output name 2>": {
                "LinkedServiceName":{
                    "referenceName": "AzureStorageLinkedService2",
                    "type": "LinkedServiceReference"

                }, 
                "FilePath":"path4"
            }

        },
        "globalParameters": {
            "<Parameter 1 Name>": "<parameter value>",
            "<parameter 2 name>": "<parameter 2 value>"
        }
    }
}`

Comment: Yes I used trigger after publishing but getting this error: Activity MLActivity failed: Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: item

Comment: Seems you pipeline payload structure is not correct. I have updated my answer

Answer (score 0):

I got this working in Data Factory v2, so apologies if you are using v1.

Try putting the `linkedServiceName` as an object in the JSON outside of the `typeProperties` and use the following structure:

```
"linkedServiceName": {
  "referenceName": "PredictionAzureML",
  "type": "LinkedServiceReference"
}
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: Hi Jon, I modified the JSON as per you answer. But now I am getting this error: Activity MLActivity failed: Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: item

Comment: @UtsavDatta looks like we have progress! That error looks to me like it's coming from calling your ML model. Can you check that the input matches what your model expects?